# ODATA service for to get sharepoint listview

Tags: odata, sharepoint-2013

I using SharePoint 2013 server, i need to develop an application which need to fetch SharePoint listview using ODATA service.

I could able to get SharePoint list data, but i need to get list view for that particular list.

regards,
RK